# How to create SQL query with each column name and its data type

Tags: python, mysql

I have a CSV file that contains 2 columns:  column names of data base and their data types. I wish to write a python code that creates SQL query with each column name and its data type. Earlier I was using a code that generalized every data type to varchar.
There are about 100 columns.
Need some ideas here..

```
# for every column in the list of columns
for i in range(number_of_columns):
    # if it is any column other than the last column
    if i != number_of_columns-1:
        # comma after every column
        CREATE_TABLE_SQL_QUERY += "%s VARCHAR(50)," %(header_list[i])
    # if it is the last column
    else:
        # no comma after last column
        CREATE_TABLE_SQL_QUERY += "%s VARCHAR(50))" %(header_list[i])

# prints the SQL query the needs to be executed for this file's table 
print(CREATE_TABLE_SQL_QUERY)
```

Comment: could tell us what issue are you facing and you need to show the content of CSV as well to understand what actually you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your csv is like below (table_schema.csv):

```
name, type
Setting, text
Value, integer
```

you can use something more or less like this, with csv module

```
import csv

with open('table_schema.csv', 'rt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    sql_parts = [] 
    headers = ['name', 'type']
    schema = csv.DictReader(f, headers)

    for col_def in list(schema)[1:]:# get rid of header line
        sql_parts.append('{} {}'.format(
            col_def['name'].strip(),
            col_def['type'].strip()))

    sql = 'create table settings(' + ', '.join(sql_parts) + ');'
    print(sql)

# or using reader instead of DictReader

with open('table_schema.csv', 'rt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    sql_parts = []
    columns = 2
    schema = csv.reader(f)

    for row in list(schema)[1:]: # get rid of header line
        if row != []:
            sql_parts.append('{} {}'.format(row[0].strip(), row[1].strip()))

    sql = 'create table settings(' + ', '.join(sql_parts) + ');'
    print(sql)
```

Both will output

```
create table settings(Setting text, Value integer);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a (A) list of types corresponding to column_names, or (B) make a list of (column_name, column_type) tuples?

You could generate your SQL Query/DDL with this.

Example using approach B:

```
table_schema = [("ID", "int"), ("NAME", "VARCHAR(50)"), ("NICKNAME", "VARCHAR(50)")]

DDL = ','.join(('{name} {type}'.format(name=col_name, type=col_type) for (col_name, col_type) in table_schema))
```

The resulting `DDL` string looks like:

```
'ID int,NAME VARCHAR(50),NICKNAME VARCHAR(50)'
```

With your existing dataset (2-column csv), you can build the `table_schema` list of (col_name, col_type) pairs and apply this approach.